# Change data validation column if values in another column equals to X or Y

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In sheet 'Template', I have a data validation column B and I would like to change the value in this column, if value in column AB equals X or Y. Otherwise, I want the value in column B to be the same.

---

I found the following script which doesn't make much sense to me

```
function Test1() {

   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var s = ss.getSheetByName("Template");
   var numRows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();
   var range;

  /* Loop through Column AB and find cells equal to order payment
  and set Column B value based on it */

   for (var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
      range = s.getRange('AB' + i );
      if (range.getValue() == "X") {
        range.offset(0, 6).setValue("X"); 
      }
     else {
       range.offset(0,6).setValue("NO");
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. This site isn't intendent for people who know nothing about programming. Considering this, please spend some time learning the pretty basics of programming using JavaScript. Perhaps starting by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets might be helpful for you.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0):

please check if this code works for you:

```
function Test1() {

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var s = ss.getSheetByName("Template");
 // 27 = number of columns
 var sheetContent = s.getRange(1,2,s.getLastRow(),27).getValues(); 

 for (var i = 0; i < sheetContent.length; i++) {
  if(sheetContent[i][26] == "X" || sheetContent[i][26] == "Y"){
   //You can replace the updated value by anything you want it to be.
   sheetContent[i][0] = "Updated Value";
  }
 }
 s.getRange(1,2,sheetContent.length,sheetContent[0].length).setValues(sheetContent);
}
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
function Test1() {
   const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   const sh= ss.getSheetByName("Template");
   const vs = sh.getRange(1,2,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()
   let a = vs.map((r,i) => {
     if(r[27] == "X" || r[27] == "Y") {
       return ["Yes"];
     } else {
       return [r[1]];
     }
   });
   sh.getRange(1,2,a.length, a[0].length).setValues(a);
}
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Comment: @Adriaan I wasn't sure that it would and I didn't have ops data to test it.